# How to select * from three tables?

Tags: mysql, database, join, relational-database

I have three tables venues,services and vendorDetails. I want to get all the columns from all the tables.

I tried join on two tables but I am getting 1 record 3 times, getting duplicate records.

query:

```
SELECT venues.venueId,venues.venue_name,venues.latitude,venues.longitude,venues.active,services.serviceId,services.service_name,services.latitude,services.longitude,services.active FROM `venues`,`services` WHERE venues.vendorId = services.vendorId
```

records :

```
venueId
venue_name
latitude
longitude
active
serviceId
service_name
latitude
longitude
active
4
siddhi hall
-2.8437453
23.3823545
1
1
DJ siddhi
1211
4545
1
4
siddhi hall
-2.8437453
23.3823545
1
2
siddhi  cateror
0
0
1
4
siddhi hall
-2.8437453
23.3823545
1
3
flowerist
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
5
siddhi cafe
0
0
1
1
DJ siddhi
1211
4545
1
5
siddhi cafe
0
0
1
2
siddhi  cateror
0
0
1
5
siddhi cafe
0
0
1
3
flowerist
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
6
siddhi cafe
-1.899681
22.72851
1
1
DJ siddhi
1211
4545
1
6
siddhi cafe
-1.899681
22.72851
1
2
siddhi  cateror
0
0
1
6
siddhi cafe
-1.899681
22.72851
1
3
flowerist
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
7
green lawn
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
1
DJ siddhi
1211
4545
1
7
green lawn
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
2
siddhi  cateror
0
0
1
7
green lawn
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
3
flowerist
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
8
hotel nashik
-2.6357434
18.4276047
1
1
DJ siddhi
1211
4545
1
8
hotel nashik
-2.6357434
18.4276047
1
2
siddhi  cateror
0
0
1
8
hotel nashik
-2.6357434
18.4276047
1
3
flowerist
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
```

venues table :

```
    Name               Type     
1   venueId            Primary  int(11)         
2   venue_name         varchar(255) 
3   venuetypeId        int(11)          
4   entry_by           varchar(255) 
5   venue_address      varchar(255) 
6   latitude           double           
7   longitude          double           
8   active             int(11)          
9   vendorId           int(11)
```

services :

```
    Name                  Type   
1   serviceIdPrimary      int(11)           
2   entry_by              varchar(255)  
3   service_name          varchar(255)  
4   service_address       varchar(255)  
5   latitude              double            
6   longitude             double            
7   servicetypeId         int(11)       
8   active                int(11)           
9   vendorId              int(11)
```

vendorDetails:

```
    Name             Type   
1   vendorIdPrimary  int(11)            
2   username         varchar(30)    
3   vendorName       varchar(255)   
4   password         varchar(200)   
5   active           int(1)         
7   vendorCountry    varchar(100)   
8   vendorState      varchar(100)   
9   vendorCity       varchar(100)   
10  vendorLocality   varchar(200)   
11  vendorArea       varchar(200)   
12  vendorAddress    text   
13  vendorPincode    varchar(200)   
14  emailId          varchar(255)   
15  mobileno         varchar(15)    
16  phoneno          varchar(15)    
17  logo1            varchar(100)   
18  logo2   varchar(100)    
19  logo3   varchar(100)    
20  venueId int(11)         
21  entry_by    varchar(20) 
22  entry_date  varchar(20) 
23  entry_time  varchar(20) 
24  last_modify_date    varchar(20) 
25  ip_addr varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       
26  deviceToken varchar(200)
```

How can I get this? thank you..

Comment: What do you wan in result-set? All the services of a vendor?

Comment: yes all the services and venues of vendor and also vendor details, vendor no,address ,name. @AlokPatel

Comment: `venues` and `services` not directly connected with each other. So you combine result of only vendors and it's services. If you put join on `vendors` and `venues` it will cause repetitive results as one vendor may have multiple venues and may provide multiple services.

Comment: I wanted to search venues and services of a vendor. your option is also fine.. then I have to create two different API's to get venues and services by vendor. could you please suggest a query?@AlokPatel

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning!

If you really want to get all columns from all of the three tables you can simply select `*` of them:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3;
```

Depending on the tables it can take a bit longer to request all the columns.

Comment: I get duplicate records by this.@Otterbein

Comment: You get alle columns from all tables together. When you have two tables with the same column-Names you'll get both of them named the same. To avoid this you have to select them one by one and give them alias names like `SELECT column1 AS alias_name, ... FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
SELECT * FROM venues INNER JOIN services USING(vendor_Id);
```

at least for your 2 tables and as long as you have the exact same columnname in your tables it works for 3 and more ofc. but i am not sure if you have just missformated your tables in your question or your ID of vendors is really vendorIdPrimary

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
    tableA a
        inner join
    tableB b
        on a.common = b.common
        inner join 
    TableC c
        on b.common = c.common
```

You must define the Common Column within those three table.